# Problema con DOUBLE en Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

El problema es que necesito que el DOUBLE no imprima con notación científica.
Cómo puedo hacer eso? Lo que quiero es que el resultado sin importar qué tan largo sea se imprima.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo de dato `double` es un número de punto flotante; cuando se excede de un valor específico, utiliza forzadamente la notación científica. Si necesitás utilizar enteros o racionales muy grandes, te recomiendo veas estas clases/librerías:

- [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`, en la librería estándar de .NET 4.0+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)
- [`BigRational` de Base Class Libraries](http://bcl.codeplex.com/)

No las he probado; pero espero que te sirvan. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Pero cuando se hace uso de decimales?

Comment: **Siempre se utilizan los decimales**; aunque en algunos casos cuando se convierte a `String` lo que queda después de la coma son ceros, entonces no los imprime. Para que comprendas lo que digo, fijate cómo funciona `double` en .NET: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Gracias, amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la sobrecarga del método [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) en la que se especifica el formato.

Por ejemplo:

```
double d = Double.Max;
d.ToString("F");
```